# How do I make shadows under my images?

Tags: css

How do I make a shadow under an image to give that hover effect without using any images?

Comment: [`box-shadow` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: It would be good to do a simple google search before posting something like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use the CSS box shadow:

```
#example1 {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a CSS3 [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow), like this:

```
img {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/M4ukJ/1/)

[CSS3.info Tutorial](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

---

To give the image a "hover effect" using `box-shadow`, use the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) selector.

```
img:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/M4ukJ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
div {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```